# Do blinds affect Kharazim's heal?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

If Johanna, Cassian or Lili (etc) blind Kharazim, does it affect his healing or does he still heal others after *hitting* even though they *miss*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kharazim doesn't heal if he doesn't **hit**

You need to take the blood of your enemies to replenish your own!

Comment: That's so morbid :)